# Laravel count data field in table row

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have one table that has many fields,

Is it possible to count how many fields that filled?

I tried count() but seems doesnt work correctly, it only count the rows of the table

The purpose is i want to take the percentage of each student's completed task

This is the view from the page
[image]

This is the table
[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the data looks like? instead of a picture of it rendered. e.g. what is the `1,2,3,4` fields called on the model?

Comment: okaay i will edit the post

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable than me can answer your question. I want to suggest a way to store this data. Let's say you had 4 questions. First answer was No, rest of them were Yes. You could convert that to 0111 and store decimal of that in the database (e.g. 7). When displaying, convert 7 to 0111. You could also find out how many were Yes and No using string comparisons. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your table structure is messy.
why not, setup a one to many relation instead of doing that.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

I would also suggest you use increment, every new task completed you increment the value. Please refer to this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries.